# No java command after sudo apt-get install default-jdk

Tags: apt, deb

I had some trouble with java so I manually removed the contents of `/usr/lib/jvm` directory. That was probably not a good idea, cause I have now bigger trouble to make java working again. I tried to install via `sudo apt-get install default-jdk` or directly install openjdk 7 jdk, but there is no `java` program in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/` after installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to re-install the JDK explicitly:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

That will restore the contents of `/usr/lib/jvm/`. As it stands I reckon `apt-get` thinks the JDK is installed, even though you removed the files manually; so when you asked it to re-install, it figured it didn't need to do anything...